# Getting out of the first room in Dark in Human: Fall Flat?

Tags: human-fall-flat

I'm playing the latest DLC of Human: Fall Flat, and am stuck at the first scene of the new level. Anyone help me get out?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a youtuber that does the full level (SPOILERS!).

He uses a block to stand on and jump up onto the wooden planks. From there you can make it to the right over the door.